# How to clean up obsolete Lando bridges?

Tags: docker, networking, lando

In my Network manager I see a great number of Bridge configurations, automatically created during my Lando experiments. Is there a tool, lando or docker command to clean up this mess, only leaving bridge networking of the two projects I am presently developing under Lando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `docker network prune` [removes all unused networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_prune), but **should be used with caution**. Note that you can [filter networks to remove](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_prune/#filtering), according to labels.

If your automatically created networks have labels (for example let's say `created=auto`), you can run :

```
docker network prune \
    --filter "label=created=auto"
```

to remove such networks.

If there is no labels, you can filter by time, for example :

```
docker network prune \
    --filter until=1d
```

This will remove all networks created more than 1 day ago.